# Cascading dropdown lists from single table in MVC (Razor)

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My query is to make two cascading dropdown lists which fetches data from single table.
My table is like :

[image]

**My Controller :**

```
    public JsonResult GetYear()
    {
        string UserName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        return Json(dbContext.EmployeeSalaries.Where(f => f.UserName == UserName).GroupBy(f => f.Year).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetMonth(string year)
    {
        string UserName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        IEnumerable<string> monthList = dbContext.EmployeeSalaries.Where(a => a.Year == year && a.UserName == UserName).Select(u => u.Month).ToList();

        return Json(monthList);
    }
```

Here I'm first filling **Year Drop down list**, based on the selection fills the **Month Drop Down List**. For e.g. Here for **UserName = 1832**, there is one year i.e. 2017, and three months (May, June, July) of data. So when the user selects 2017, the month-dropdown list should populate May, June, July.

**Problem:** The Month dropdown list displays 'undefined' in the list.

[image]

**View and jQuery used:**

```
      @Html.DropDownList("ddlYear", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select year", new { @style = "width:250px;" })

      @Html.DropDownList("ddlMonth", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select month", new { @style = "width:250px;" })

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/SalaryProcess/GetYear",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#ddlYear').append('<option value="' + value.Year + '">' + value.Year + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });

    $('#ddlYear').change(function () {
       // $('#ddlMonth').empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/SalaryProcess/GetMonth",
            data: { year: $('#ddlYear').val() },
            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#ddlMonth').append('<option value="' + value.MonthId + '">' + value.Month + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Please suggest solution to this problem.

Comment: Because your returning `IEnumerable<string>` and `string` does not contain properties `MonthId` and `Month`. As a side note, there are other issues with your code and suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem with your `GetMonth` method. You are selecting only `month` column from the EmployeeSalaries table but in view you are using them as model properties(`value.monthId` and `value.month`). Please use following code and it should work:

```
public JsonResult GetMonth(string year)
{
    string UserName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

    var monthList = dbContext.EmployeeSalaries
        .Where(a => a.Year == year && a.UserName == UserName)
        .Select(x => new { MonthId = x.MonthId, Month = x.Month });
    return Json(monthList);
}
```

Comment: Sending all properties of the object just degrades performance (create an anonymous object containing only the 2 properties that are needed)

Comment: @Sameep Baxi, please try this code and let me know if you are still facing the problem. Please cast your up vote if it works(will be helpful for others).

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly! Thanks for the explanation. Upvoted the answer too!